# How do you scale threat modeling?

Tags: threat-modeling

Small threat models are relatively easy to build but building and maintaining a threat model that contains a few dozen components becomes difficult pretty quickly.

What tools do you use to collaborate across teams to build and maintain large threat models?

Specifically looking to address the needs of:

1. a highly distributed organization
2. a system that does not have clear separations of concerns that can be allocated to a single team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same tools that they use to build and maintain large complex features: version control, engineering process artifacts (like specs and architecture overviews), and bugs/task/issue tracking.

So let's say Alice does a STRIDE analysis and finds a set of spoofing issues.  As part of doing that, she adds some trust boundaries to an architecture picture, and updates the version in the wiki.

She documents the set of threats and checks it in as a .txt file next to the code for the component.  Some apply to her component and become issues to investigate, some apply to Bob's component, and so she opens bugs for him, and some are unclear, so she shoots off an email which leads to a discussion meeting.

(This is a pretty broad question, so if my answer isn't helpful, let me re-frame your question a little: What tools do your teams use to collaborate across their large projects, and in what ways do those not work for threat models?)

Comment: waves at Adam Shostack, godfather of threat modeling :-D. Thank you, a good answer